# Remove underline column name entity spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyu4f.png)When i create an entity and define column name the underscore appear with color gray.
I want to remove underline in the column name entity.
I haven't found anything in the settings or Google.
How can i turn it on/off.
Thank you everyone for helping me answer this question.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you add the code here rather than an image. Might also be useful to have it online somewhere in a code sandbox to help debug a minimum reproducible version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What IDE/Text editor are you using?
Try to use a different IDE and see if its still there

Edit:
I just noticed that your column name is exactly the same as the variable name, in this case, you don't need to specify the attribute name in the column annotation, this would probably remove the gray line from the name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using Intellij 2023

Comment: My pleasure, and I just noticed that your column name is exactly the same as the variable name, in that case, you don't need to specify the attribute name in the column annotation, this would probably remove the gray line from the name

Comment: I found a way to turn off underscore: Settings->Editor->Language Defaults->String->Highlighted reference. Uncheck Effects. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).